# Why does kivy.Builder.load_file() fail to load screens?

Tags: python, kivy

I am experimenting with a screen manager for app development. I try to use the load file function of the builder, but it fails to add screens to the screen manager.

My code is this

```
# filename: manager.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Home(Screen):
    pass

class Settings(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
 
class MngrApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("manager.kv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MngrApp().run()
```

```
# filename: manager.kv
Manager:
    Home:
    Settings:

<Home>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto settings'
            on_press: root.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<Settings>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.current = 'home'
```

My output is

```
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.
```

I am wondering if I need to reformat something? Maybe just start over? I can't

Comment: it seems problem is `kv` doesn't know that `Home`/`Settings` are `Screen`. And If I use `<Home@Screen>` then there is conflict with `class Home(Screen)`. It seems it would be simpler to remove `Manager` from `kv` and create it in code (and it needs to add screens to manager in code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is already a kivy `Settings` class. Just change the name of your class from `Settings` to something else.

Comment: This returns the same error when I rename my class to SettingsScreen.